# How to package ListViews for Custom Metadata Types?

Tags: package, list-view, custom-metadata

Is there a way to package ListViews for Custom Metada Types? I can't see these ListViews when trying to add them to a package, but maybe there is a workaround?

Comment: +1 - They are also not available via Metadata API

Answer (score 3):

We're aware of this bug and planning a fix. I don't think we have a KI for it yet, but the bug number is W-4489231 if that's in any way helpful for tracking.

Update: KI is https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018BCTQA2

Update2: Fixed in Summer '18.